# Setting up a scraping function to run on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, halacha-theory, modern-times

What halachic (if any) considerations are there if one has a function that is scraping a website and then populating a database with the data running over Shabbos? It will finish on Shabbos and when it finishes it writes the ones that failed into a note.

Comment: An excellent question to post late Friday afternoon

Comment: How is this different than any other melacha [that one may start Erev Shabbos and let continue on Shabbos](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.252.1)?

Comment: @alberko yes it does! Thank you!

Comment: @robev those finish by themselves, this could be you setting it up to be done on shabbos specifically